# Why am I getting dpkg error while installing rundeck?

Tags: rundeck, dpkg

I am getting the following output when I install rundeck with this command `sudo dpkg -i rundeck_3.3.13.20210614-1_all.deb`
The error is:

```
usermod: user rundeck is currently used by process 1151
dpkg: error processing package rundeck (--install):
 installed rundeck package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 8
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rundeck
```

Comment: *user rundeck is currently used by process 1151*  looks like there is something running (pid 1151) which uses the user rundeck. Thats why you can not install the package. Can you check what the process 1151 is?

Comment: It's this procees
rundeck     1151  0.0  0.2  18408  9532 ?        Ss   06:25   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you create manually a `rundeck` user before installing the DEB package. The DEB package creates that user as a part of the Rundeck installation, so, you don't need to create the `rundeck` user manually, take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/linux-deb.html#installing-on-ubuntu-or-debian-linux-distributions) to learn how to install Rundeck correctly on Debian-based systems.

If you want to keep that user `rundeck` created by you, you have the option to use WAR-based installation, [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/jar.html) you can learn how to install it.

Check [this](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/pCPflKeDbKg), which is the same issue.